# Removing lines from an image a notebook for digit detection python

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr

I need to remove the lines from the image below of numbers on a piece of ruled paper without causing my digits any distortion. Without this, my digit detection algorithm to fails as there are artefacts of the ruling lines of the piece of paper in the region of interest's.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjtnldwme4qqc4v/Issue_file.jpeg?dl=0 "Issue Image"]

a cleaner version of the file without any artefacts
[image: Cleaner version of file]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic task for Fourier-domain transform.

1. Perform Fourier transform:

`import numpy as np
    from scipy.misc import imshow, imsave, imread 
    img = imread("10XIn.jpg")[:,:,:3]
    imggray = np.mean(img, -1)
    imfft = np.fft.fft2(imggray)
    mags = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(imfft))
    angles = np.angle(np.fft.fftshift(imfft))
    visual = np.log(mags)
    visual2 = (visual - visual.min()) / (visual.max() - visual.min())*255`

visual2 will look like following:
[image]

Note the diagonal line across the center  - it represents your lines.

Now, I've manually created the mask for this line, but idealy you could filter it out programmatucally
[image]

Then we read the mask and paint out the line:

    `mask = imread("fftimg4_mask.jpg")[:,:,:3]
    mask = (np.mean(mask,-1) > 20)
    visual[mask] = np.mean(visual)`

And then reverse the fft:

    `newmagsshift = np.exp(visual)
    newffts = newmagsshift * np.exp(1j*angles)
    newfft = np.fft.ifftshift(newffts)
    imrev = np.fft.ifft2(newfft)
    newim2 = 255 - np.abs(imrev).astype(np.uint8)
    imsave("fftimg2.jpg",  newim2  )`

Here is newim2[image]

Of course, you could do more accurate patching in fourier space and also you could apply the result back to the original image to keep colors, but I think this post illustrates the idea.

Comment: this is great will try it.  There is a bounty for a similar problem on another site you should give it a try. https://www.freelancer.com/contest/Digit-Detection-on-ruled-paper-188586.html

Comment: Hi I tried using hough lines to detect the line but it did not work as it returned too many lines, is there any other way? But it does work otherwise to a certain extent

Comment: appropriate threshold and then hough line should work. Actually, just a threshold plus zeroing unrelated areas can be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this might be a bitcomplicated as the color of the notebook lines is quite close to the color of digits, as it seems from your example. I presume, that the green boxes are you addition and not part of the data itself.

You don't state which framework you use, so I will provide only some general tips how to approach this problem.

First step would be some thresholding. You can use either binary thresholding or better some adaptive thresholding with correctly sized windows. You will have to experiment on this. Result of threshholding will be binary image. Still with lines.

Second step will be to use morphological operations to clear the image. If you are not sure what morphology is, look at this [morphology tutorial](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/open.htm).

Around half way through, there are some examples of removing lines from images. The biggest problem is, that some number also contain horizontal lines. So one option will be to use rather small morphology kernel (maybe 3 rows and 1 column), as the notebook lines are thinner. And update the recognizer, to recognize even distorted numbers. This should be doable, because all the digits will be distored in same way.

Comment: unfortunately the distortion would be infinite in possibilities so the digit detection would fail

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to exploit the known structure.

1. deskew the image (skew can be found with Hough transform in opencv)
2. locate peaks in row sums
3. physically clone pixels above and below lines

I just implemented this for another dataset, example attached. This could be tuned further.

[image: Sample result]